# How to get currentPath and dynamic segment in Controller

Tags: ember.js

Is there any 'ember' way to get the current dynamic segment? Its available in the Route via params, how to access them from ArrayControllers ?

Any solution like [this.get('controllers.application.currentPath')](http://emberjs.com/guides/understanding-ember/debugging/#toc_get-current-route-name-path) ? Of course window.location.hash is there, but an ember way would be more efficient.

**[UPDATE]**

Basically this is what I am doing (its a photo gallery).

There is only one **Model** (photo). Her is one sample:

```
{
  id: 1,
  name: 'brad-pitt',
  date_added: 'Sat Apr 05 2014 23:04:35 GMT+0530 (IST)',
  link: 'example.com',
  image: 'http://www.somewebsite.com/image.jpg',
  rank: 20
}
```

**Routes**:

```
 App.Router.map(function(){
   this.route('index', {path: '/'});  
   this.route('photos', {path: ':name'}); 
 })
```

`/` shows all the models, sorted by rank.

`/brad-pitt` Again, shows **ALL** the models, but filters the ones which have name = 'brad-pitt'

`/brad-pitt?p=1` Shows **ALL** the models, but filters name = "brad-pitt" AND also highlights the one with ID 1 (masonry `m2` to be specific).

**Controller**:

```
App.PhotosController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  needs: ['application'],
  itemController: 'photo',
  queryParams: ['p'],
  p: null,

  pictures: function() {
    var p = this.get('p');
    var pics = this.get('model');

    // console.log(this.get('controllers.application.currentRouteName'));

    if(p) {
      return pics.filterProperty('id', p);
    } else {
      return pics.filterProperty('name', 'some-one'); // <- THIS NEEDS TO BE DYNAMIC
    }
  }.property('p', 'model')
});


App.PhotoController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  link_out: function() {
    return 'http://' + this.get('link')
  }.property()
});
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Trying to access routes from your controllers is just wrong. You already have access to other controllers with `needs` and you can call `send` to emit an action in the route and bubble up if necessary.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want? The controller should not know about the router's domain. Why not just take the data you want in the route and pass it through in the model?

Comment: Added the specifics. @jasonpgignac - How do you take the data and pass it to the models? I have tried to do this with the model property of a Route like this return this.store.find('photo', {name: 'some-one'}); - But this never works. Throws some map ing issues.

Comment: Can you JSBin it? I think I'm having trouble visualizing where your problem is.